# counter example on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, counter

I want to implement a counter example and see how rails responds to user actions. Like I want to have a button on view & when user clicks it the counter should be invoked and it should show the count. Any help would be appreciated ( like a schematic skeleton). I am a newbie to the rails.

Thanks!

```
def count(x)
  x +=x
end
```

I wish to have the `x` as `Button Click`. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Cool. Uh, what's your question? Do you want us to give you some conceptual help? Point you to some tutorials? Show you an example of something similar? Have you managed anything yourself, and you'd like the community to comment on how next to proceed? Sorry, it just seems like your question is a bit poorly defined. Could you please elaborate a little more? Also, welcome to StackOverflow ^^

Comment: I defined something like a `counter` method in place. But I dont know how can something like button should be passed as parameter to the method. If you can help in that it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked this question once before, and got what looks like a perfectly sensible answer: there's some MVC architecture that you don't have a good grip on yet, and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html is probably a good place to begin. You'll need a Model, or some other database element, to store your counter variable; you'll need a controller that's responsible for taking input from the View and manipulating your Model, and View with some code on it that invokes your Controller.

There isn't really an easy "type this code here" solution - there's a whole underlying architecture that needs to be understood. The good news is that once you have MVC down, making a counter of this type should come pretty easily.

Comment: @Clone blahman and Mark are perfectly right. I think before having a look to MVC you may review HTTP / client-server interaction basics. A button cannot fire your `count` method directly. You'll have to make the browser send an HTTP request to the server.